# Problems with bibliography style file in TeXworks

Tags: bibliographies, packages, miktex, texworks

I'm using TeXworks as my editor in writing an article, where the bibliography style has to be `vancouver`. It has previously worked just fine, and if I set the style to `plain` I have no problems, but as soon as I set it to `vancouver` I encounter this problem.

I can open the package manager just fine manually, and I have also updated MikTeX

Here's the console output:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: filename.aux

======================================================================
miktex-bibtex.exe: Cannot start MiKTeX package manager.
miktex-bibtex.exe: Data: Invalid syntax

======================================================================
I couldn't open style file vancouver.bst
---line 16 of file filename.aux
 : \bibstyle{vancouver
 :                    }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file filename.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Thankful for any suggestions and sorry if this question is badly defined, I've only just stated using LaTeX, and all of this is completely new to me!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: vancouver.bst is missing on your system and bibtex is trying to install it on-the-fly and fails. On my system it worked fine so I can't tell you what is wrong on your system, but you could try to install the missing vancouver package with the package manager.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I thought that all the packages I could see were already installed, but now I see of course that not all of them are.

Answer (score 2):

`vancouver.bst` is missing on your system and `bibtex` is trying to install it on-the-fly and fails. On my system it worked fine so I can't tell you what is wrong on your system, but you could try to install the missing `vancouver` package with the package manager.